# Does the forgetful functor from a pointed $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category only create weakly contractible colimits?

Tags: higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits

Consider an $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category $\mathcal{C}$ with a terminal object $1$. (I'm particularly interested in the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is a topos.) It is known that the forgetful functor $U$ from the under-category ${1}/{\mathcal{C}}$ to $\mathcal{C}$ creates colimits of diagrams with weakly contractible index categories. Is there an example of a diagram $F : \mathcal{I} \to {1}/{\mathcal{C}}$ such that

- $\mathcal{I}$ is *not* weakly contractible
- $U$ still creates the colimit of $F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short answer is that if $C$ is the terminal category, then $1/C \to C$ is an equivalence, and hence creates all colimits.

Less flippantly, we can take $C$ to be the ordinary topos of sets. Then the forgetful functor creates $I$-shaped colimits if $I$ is connected.

If $C$ is cocomplete, then the colimit of $F$ in $1/C$ is the pushout of a diagram
$$
1 \leftarrow colim_I 1 \to colim_I F
$$
and so the critical question is whether the colimit of the constant diagram with value $1$ is equivalent to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was too open-ended. I'm thinking of $\mathcal{C}$ having untruncated objects. (I'm secretly thinking of models of homotopy type theory.) Are there examples of cocomplete $\mathcal{C}$ with untruncated objects where $I$ is not weakly contractible but $\mathsf{colim}_I{1} \simeq 1$?

Comment: @PerryHart Sure. If C is the category of pointed spaces, or any other category with a zero object, then $1/C \to C$ is also an equivalence.

Comment: I guess my point is that this would be a pretty special property of the category $C$. Here is an alternative formulation. Given an $(\infty,1)$-category $C$, there is a functor $e: C \to Spaces$, $X \mapsto Map_C(1,X)$. The forgetful functor will create $I$-shaped colimits if and only if, for any $X$, the space of maps from the nerve $NI$ to $e(X)$ is equivalent to the space of constant maps. (So if "enough spaces" are of the form $e(X)$, then the forgetful functor creates colimits; this explains why you don't see it when mapping spaces are truncated.)